# How can I get excel files or CSV for real case of using thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard, workload

please if anybody can help me with a CSV file of data take from thingsboard use case for checking the workload characteristics of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature for this in Thingsboard PE.

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/csv-xls-data-export/

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to do this in the community edition,
but you can create your own widget to do the following:

1. Use the thingsboard http-api to get the data (see https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/)
2. Process/Format the data to CSV
3. Create an Achor-Element in the widget to download the CSV (see [How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server))